# Problemas acceso datos API REST GOOGLE FIT

Tags: google-api, firebase-auth

[google-fit]  Buenas, estoy intentando acceder a los datos de la API REST de GOOGLE FIT usando el AccesToken que me da la autentificacion con Firebase y me da "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.", en cambio si uso el AccesToken proporcionado por el playground si me va correctamente, como puedo arreglarlo? Es posible que sea porque no tengo la app verificada aún?